# Error al ingresar usuario en java

Tags: java, sql-server, javafx, netbeans-8.2

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto y ahora necesito crear una vista desde el lado de javafx, la cual sera para registro de usuarios nuevos pero cuando intento agregar me tira el error : "Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException", desde el lado de SQLServer si puedo agregar usuarios pero desde Netbeans no, ya varias veces me ha pasado pero esta vez no lo puedo solucionar, ya que este problema se debe a nombres mal escritos o la incompatibilidad de tipos pero ya revise todo eso y ese no es el problema, sin mas opciones de buscar el error, le di un debug al proyecto y me di cuenta que hay un campo donde me indica error

[image: Error]

y en los otros campos no da error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En teoría el error dice que viene desde el bean pero no se porque las propiedades de mi bean son estas:

```
private int codigoUsuario;
private String nombreUsuario;
private String email;
private String usuario;
private String contraseña;
private String tipoDeUsuario;
```

En este bean, tengo todos los getters and setters de las propiedades

Mensaje del error:

```
 Executing C:\Users\bryan\Documents\NetBeansProjects\SportStore2017090\dist\run582449146\SportStore2017090.jar using platform C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre/bin/java
 Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8413)
at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$353(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1771)
... 48 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.jhonylopez.bean.Usuario
at org.jhonylopez.controller.RegistroController.agregar(RegistroController.java:130)
at org.jhonylopez.controller.RegistroController.nuevo(RegistroController.java:113)
... 58 more
```

Código de ResgistroController:

public class RegistroController implements Initializable{

```
private enum operaciones {NUEVO, GUARDAR, CANCELAR, NINGUNO};
private operaciones tipoDeOperacion = operaciones.NINGUNO;
private ObservableList<String> listaTipoDeUsuario;
private ObservableList<Usuario> listaUsuario;
private Principal escenarioPrincipal;
private Boolean salida = false;

@FXML private TextField txtNombreUsuario;
@FXML private TextField txtEmailUsuario;
@FXML private TextField txtUsuario;
@FXML private TextField txtPassword;

@FXML private ComboBox cmbTipoUsuario;

@FXML private Button btnNuevo;
@FXML private Button btnCancelar;

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    cmbTipoUsuario.setItems(getTipoDeUsuarios());
}

public ObservableList<Usuario> getUsuarios()
{
    ArrayList<Usuario> lista = new ArrayList<>();
    try
    {
        PreparedStatement procedimiento = Conexion.getInstancia().getConexion().prepareCall("{call sp_ListarUsuarios}");
        ResultSet resultado = procedimiento.executeQuery();
        while(resultado.next())
        {
            lista.add(new Usuario(resultado.getInt("codigoUsuario"), resultado.getString("nombreUsuario"),
                resultado.getString("email"), resultado.getString("usuario"), resultado.getString("contraseña"),
                resultado.getString("tipoDeUsuario")));
        }
    }catch(SQLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        e.getMessage();
    }
    return listaUsuario = FXCollections.observableList(lista);
}

public ObservableList<String> getTipoDeUsuarios()
{
    ArrayList<String> lista = new ArrayList<>();

    lista.add("root");
    lista.add("admin");
    lista.add("sa");
    lista.add("invitado");

    return listaTipoDeUsuario = FXCollections.observableList(lista);
}

public void nuevo()
{
    switch(tipoDeOperacion)
    {
        case NINGUNO:
            activarControles();
            limpiarControles();
            btnNuevo.setText("Guardar");
            btnCancelar.setText("Cancelar");
            tipoDeOperacion = operaciones.GUARDAR;
            break;

        case GUARDAR:
            agregar();
            desactivarControles();
            btnNuevo.setText("Nuevo");
            btnCancelar.setText("Cancelar");
            tipoDeOperacion = operaciones.NINGUNO;
            limpiarControles();
            break;
    }
}

public void agregar()
{
    Usuario registro = new Usuario();
    registro.setNombreUsuario(txtNombreUsuario.getText());
    registro.setEmail(txtEmailUsuario.getText());
    registro.setUsuario(txtUsuario.getText());
    registro.setContraseña(txtPassword.getText());
    registro.setTipoDeUsuario(((Usuario)cmbTipoUsuario.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem()).getTipoDeUsuario());
    try
    {
        PreparedStatement procedimiento = Conexion.getInstancia().getConexion().prepareCall("{call sp_AgregarUsuario(?,?,?,?,?)}");
        procedimiento.setString(1, registro.getNombreUsuario());
        procedimiento.setString(2, registro.getEmail());
        procedimiento.setString(3, registro.getUsuario());
        procedimiento.setString(4, registro.getContraseña());
        procedimiento.setString(5, registro.getTipoDeUsuario());
        procedimiento.execute();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Usuario añadido");
        limpiarControles();

    }catch(SQLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        e.getMessage();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al ingresar usuario, por favor intentarlo otra vez");
    }
}

public void cancelar()
{
    switch(tipoDeOperacion)
    {
        case GUARDAR:
            desactivarControles();
            limpiarControles();
            btnNuevo.setText("Nuevo");
            tipoDeOperacion = operaciones.NINGUNO;
            break;
        default:            
    } 
}

public Usuario buscarUsuarios(int codigoUsuario)
{
    Usuario resultado = null;
    try
    {
        PreparedStatement procedimiento = Conexion.getInstancia().getConexion().prepareCall("{call sp_BuscarUsuario(?)}");
        procedimiento.setInt(1, codigoUsuario);
        ResultSet registro = procedimiento.executeQuery();
        while(registro.next())
        {
            resultado = new Usuario(registro.getInt("codigoUsuario"), registro.getString("nombreUsuario"),
                    registro.getString("email"), registro.getString("usuario"), registro.getString("contraseña"), 
                    registro.getString("tipoDeUsuario"));
        }

    }catch(SQLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        e.getMessage();
    }
    return resultado;
}

public void limpiarControles()
{
    txtNombreUsuario.setText("");
    txtEmailUsuario.setText("");
    txtUsuario.setText("");
    txtPassword.setText("");

    cmbTipoUsuario.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
}

public void desactivarControles()
{
    txtNombreUsuario.setEditable(false);
    txtEmailUsuario.setEditable(false);
    txtUsuario.setEditable(false);
    txtPassword.setEditable(false);

    cmbTipoUsuario.setDisable(true);
}

public void activarControles()
{
    txtNombreUsuario.setEditable(true);
    txtEmailUsuario.setEditable(true);
    txtUsuario.setEditable(true);
    txtPassword.setEditable(true);

    cmbTipoUsuario.setDisable(false);
}

public Principal getEscenarioPrincipal() {
    return escenarioPrincipal;
}

public void setEscenarioPrincipal(Principal escenarioPrincipal) {
    this.escenarioPrincipal = escenarioPrincipal;
}       

}
```

Comment: Qué versión de JDK estás utilizando??

Comment: Puedes agregar la traza completa del error??

Comment: Tengo instalados el jdk1.7.0_80 y el jdk1.8.0_161

Comment: Cuál es la línea 130 de la clase RegistroController? Mejor, agrega el código de esa clase, en especial el del método `agregar()`.

Comment: Esta bien lo agregaré

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que estás teniendo se debe a que el ComboBox `cmbTipoUsuario` contiene objetos de tipo `String` y estás intentando castearlo a `Usuario`:

```
 (Usuario) cmbTipoUsuario.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem()
```

Esto provoca que se lance la excepción `java.lang.ClassCastException`, que es la causa del error.

Si te fijas al final de la traza del error te lo dice claramente:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.jhonylopez.bean.Usuario
```

Para solucionarlo elimina el casting a `Usuario`, cámbialo por una a `String` y quita la llamada al método `getTipoDeUsuario()`, de esta manera:

```
registro.setTipoDeUsuario((String) cmbTipoUsuario.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
```

Comment: Sí ese era el error de mi problema, gracias.